# Image do not show after choosing file from browse button

Tags: javascript, image, forms

I'm using laravel 4 and I upload and store image using Form::file('image').
 It works correctly. But when I click browse button, it only shows uploaded image name. I want to show the uploaded image.

```
    {{ Form::open(array('route'=>'speaker.store','files' => 'true')) }}
    {{ Form::label('image','Image') }}
    {{ Form::file('image') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Save') }}
    <a href="{{ URL::route('speaker.index') }}">Cancel</a>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

For updating form, old image is displaying and I want to show new browsed image.

```
 {{ Form::model($speaker,array('route' =>array('speaker.update',$speaker->id),'method' => 'post','files' => true)) }}
    <img alt="{{ $speaker->name }}" src="{{ URL::to($speaker->image) }}">
    {{ Form::file('image') }}

    {{ Form::submit('Update') }}

    <a href="{{ URL::route('speaker.index') }}">Cancel</a>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does not. That's the default behaviour of browsers.

You have to do this client side, using JavaScript.

Give ID to the `Form::file`

```
{{ Form::file('image', array('id' => 'image-input')) }}
```

Then register handler for `change` event over this element.

```
document.getElementById('image-input').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Create `handleFileSelect` function, which does what you want.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt)
{
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
    {
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var image = document.createElement('img');
                image.src = e.target.result;

                document.body.appendChild(image);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
```

You may want to change where `image` is appended or something else...

Remember, browsers have to support HTML5 File API (FileReader and FileList here) to read files  localy.

I have written it on the fly, sorry for syntax error or similar.

Comment: I totally forgot to think the default behaviour of browsers. I'm not used to front end development. Thanks your answer.

Comment: Yes, I would like to but I tried to use the code and It doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What does not work? It does, but looks like you are too lazy to modify it to your needs.

Comment: I said I tried to use in my project and it did not fit with my code. I know I need to learn more about front end development and so I decided to finish the back end firstly and then go to the front end. So don't label if you don't know totally.